# linking problem when including python in C++ file on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I'm building user interface for usb device using MFC application on Visual Studio 2017 in C++. I've written a short script in python to read some data from a file, which I wanted to use in my program.

I've downloaded all the necessary packages for python which are specified in the Visual Studio guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/installing-python-support-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#visual-studio-2017-and-2019)

I've added in `Project -> Properties ->  C\C++ -> All Options -> Additional Include Directories` the path to `Microsoft Visul Studio\Shared\Python36_64\include`.

I also specified this path in the `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`.

In addition, I've made sue all `.pdb` files are specified in the debugging symbols.

The problem is, that when I try to build the solution I get the following error:

`LNK1104 cannot open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visul Studio\Shared\Python36_64\include.obj`

When I checked, the file include.obj isn't generated (it doesn't exist) but I don't know what do I need to do in order to create it.

I believe the problem is with my project\linker properties, but I'm not sure what exactly. I think so since when I create new python project I have no problems running python code and when I delete the `#include <Python.h>` my app works perfectly. Perhaps anyone has an idea how can I solve it?

Thank you.

EDIT:

I've tried what Barrnet Chou suggested in the comments. I did everything as written in the manual,  but keep getting the same problem. perhaps I didn't include the right paths?

I've added the following:

In `VC++ Directories` I've added in `Include Directories` and `Library Directories` the following:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\libs`
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\include`

in `C\C++ -> General` I've added

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\include`

in `Linker -> General` and `Linker -> Input`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\include`
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\libs`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could check if the libs are added in `Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories`.

If you did, I suggest you could refer to Microsoft Docs about [lnk1104](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=vs-2019).

**Cannot open file 'C:\Program.obj'**

If you see the filename C:\Program.obj in the error message, wrap your library paths in double quotes. This error happens when an unwrapped path that begins with C:\Program Files gets passed to the linker. Unwrapped paths may also cause similar errors. Typically, they show an unexpected .obj file in the root of your drive.

To fix this issue for command-line builds, check the /LIBPATH option parameters. Also check the paths specified in the LIB environment variable, and the paths specified on the command line. Make sure to use double-quotes around any paths that include spaces.

To fix this issue in the IDE, add double-quotes as necessary to the following properties for your project:

- The Library Directories property on the Configuration Properties->
  VC++ Directories property page,
- The Additional Library Directories property in the Configuration
  Properties-> Linker-> General property page,
- The Additional Dependencies property in the Configuration Properties->Linker-> Input property page.

Comment: @BarnetChou Thank you for your reply. I've edited the question. unfortunately it still doesn't work, perhaps I didn't include the right paths?

Comment: You said that `when I delete the #include <Python.h> my app works perfectly`. Could you tell me what `Python.h` is and the `app` is MFC application or python project?

Comment: Python.h is the library you need to include in C++ file in order to call python script from there as described here: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html
my app is an MFC dialog based application, and I'm writing it in C++. I want to add there a short script from python file but I'm having trouble with it... Do you have any idea what could be the problem? I have all the neccessary extension for VS 2017. Thank you

Comment: I read some documents about `mfc` import `python.h`. I suggest that you could try to set `python36.lib(Release)` or `python36_d.lib(Debug)` in `Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`. Also, you could confirm that the platform settings are consistent(x64 in `Properties` and x64 in `Solution Platforms`).